# Error evaluating JSON Path <$.element>. Returning empty result. Error>>> invalid path

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a json request where some elements are optional, if i pass them then it works fine, if i don't send these elements in the request then i get below error getting logged unnecessary, how to avoid it.
Error:

```
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseJsonPath} - #stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON Path <$.name>. Returning empty result. Error>>> invalid path
```

Code:

```
<property expression="json-eval($.name)" name="name" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: please any comments appreciated..!

Answer (score 0):

Perform a filter on the element availability first as below :

```
<filter xpath="json-eval($.name)">
   <then>
     <property expression="json-eval($.name)" name="name" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   </then>
   <else/>
</filter>
```

Reference : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Filter+Mediator

Comment: thanks for your comment @meheeka, i tried this before, when json-eval($.name) performed irrespective of in filter or property  the same error will be logged in the server logs if "name" is not passed in the request.